# Why does rewriting an equation change the limits?

Tags: limits

Why does rewriting

$$f(x) = \frac{x^3 - 1}{x -1}$$

into

$$f(x) = x^2 + x + 1$$

change the answer? In the first equation, it's obvious that $x \neq 1$, but when we solve it a little, the $x \neq 1$ completely disappears.

Wouldn't that mean if you rewrite all equations that have multiplication to include variables under the divisor, then wouldn't they all have indeterminants?

Comment: What is "the answer"? What limit are you considering?

Comment: The thing is that precisely, the limit does *not* change, so rewriting the equation this way shows you that your first expression actually had a finite limit at $x=1$, even though it looked like $x=1$ was a singularity at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changes because these are two different equations. Your first $f(x)$ is not the same as your second $f(x)$.

The first $f(x)$ implies that $x \neq 1$, as you say, so if you want to rewrite it, then you would have to explicitly state the domain:
$$f(x) = x^2 + x + 1, \quad x \neq 1$$

In other words, if you are working carefully, it is your job to make sure that the condition $x \neq 1$ does not "completely disappear".

Answer (score 1):

An expression alone is not enough to define a function. (Very few functions actually have expressions, but that's a different story.) To have a function you must also have a domain.

Usually we are lazy and just assume "the largest domain possible where the expression makes sense". But in this case, as you have discovered, that approach fails as the two expressions imply different domains. So the domain must be specified. Most easily, I think, by saying
$$
f(x)=x^2+x+1\quad (x \neq1)
$$
Or maybe you want the entire number line as domain. And in that case you would instead fix your first expression into
$$
f(x)=\cases{\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}& if $x\neq1$\\3& if $x=1$}
$$

Answer (score 1):

It does not change. As pointed out in the other answers, the domain of the first function is $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$ and  in this domain we do have $\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}=x^2+x+1.$ The difference is that the second one is defined at $x=1$, while the former is not. A simpler case where it also happens is $\frac{x}{x}=1, x\neq 0$.

More generally, we can do this whenever we have a rational function $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, with $g(a)=0$, $g$ is not identically zero, $f(a)=0$ and the multiplicity of $a$ as a zero of $f$ is not less than its multiplicity as a zero of $g$.